# How can I open erx files?

Tags: database, database-design, database-schema, axapta

I just created a table diagram from Dynamics and I cannot open the file, I tried with Erwin Data Modeler but cannot open ERX files. Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

If you have tried to open the file wth Erwin and Visio (2010) as indicated by [this MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc604309%28v=ax.50%29.aspx) page then I would say that the EXR file is corrupt.

Comment: Hi Kane, I followed the msdn article and worked for me. I used Visio Premium 2010 and after importing from the Database tab I dragged all the tables and a nice diagram appeared. Also tried with CA Erwin Data Modeler but with the Community Edition is not posible to import CA ERWin 3.x (ERX) files.